# vector times cross product

Tags: linear-algebra

> We have vectors $x, y, z$ where $z = x \times y$.

What is $x \cdot z$?

From my intuition, the cross product is perpendicular to both vectors, so dot product should be 0?

Comment: You are right, and that's in fact one of the basic properties of the vector [scalar triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Scalar_triple_product).

Answer (score 0):

Correct. If $x$ is not collinear to $y$,  $z$ defines the direction of a normal vector to the plane that both $x$ and $y$ lie in. So $z$ is normal to both. In the case where $x$ and $y$ are collinear (one is a scalar multiple of the other),  then the cross product between them is the null vector, so the assertion is trivially true.

Answer (score 0):

As defined $z$ will be perpendicular to both $x$ and $y$ from the definition of cross product and hence $x.z = 0$ since $z$ is perpendicular to both $x$ and $y$ and as dot product of any two perpendicular vectors is zero due to the involvement of $cos(90^{\circ})$ term.

Answer (score 0):

The geometric reasoning you mentioned is correct, and it probably the best way to understand what's going on.

Another option is as follows: We know that  $x \cdot z = x \cdot (x \times y)$. In general, the value of the triple product $u \cdot (v \times w)$ is given by the determinant that has $u$, $v$, $w$ as its rows. But, in our case, since $x$ occurs twice in our triple product, the determinant will have two identical rows, so its value will be zero. In short
$$
x \cdot z = x \cdot (x \times y) =
\det \left[\begin{matrix} 
\leftarrow & x & \rightarrow \\
\leftarrow & x & \rightarrow \\
\leftarrow & y & \rightarrow \\
\end{matrix} \right] = 0
$$